# How to pass dynamic values from html button to a model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please anyone know how i can use this button to pass value to the model dynamically...meaning..i have dynamic values to pass to this model...how can i do this pls...

```
//this is the button
<p> <button type="button" data-target="#exampleFormModal" data-toggle="modal"> Load</button> </p>

//from here is the model
<div id="exampleFormModal" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="exampleFormModalLabel"
          role="dialog" tabindex="-1">

            <div class="modal-dialog">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you using a ajax call?

Comment: What library are you using to make your modal?  Bootstrap?  jQuery UI?

Comment: yes Bootsrap is what i am using to call the model

Answer (score 1):

i got it...incase for anyone who might need this..

i just pass the variable, in this case laravel variable into the model ID like this id="exampleFormModal{{ $item->id}}"

```
//BUTTON..check the id
<p> <button type="button" class=" btn-block btn btn-direction btn-bottom btn-success btn-outline"  data-target="#exampleFormModal{{ $item->id}}" data-toggle="modal"> Load Truck</button> </p>


//Model ..check the ID
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleFormModal{{ $item->id}}" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="exampleFormModalLabel"
          role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
```

Comment: more suggestions needed please